# How to copy with wildcard in directory name?

Tags: shell, wildcards, cp

I would like to copy the `html` directory inside a directory like `cms_drupal_PROJ-1-2` to `/var/www`.

The last digit in the working directory is dynamic so at any given time all I know is 'cms_drupal_PROJ-1-' however there will be only 1 directory.

how can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do it like so:

```
$ cp -r /path/to.cms_drupal_PROJ-1-*/html /var/www/.
```

That will enlist a glob using `*` for the unknown character. You could also use a range like this:

```
$ cp -r cms_drupal_PROJ-1-[0-9]/html var/www/
```

Comment: Or `cms_drupal_PROJ-1-?`